# docker-compose build and http_proxy

Tags: elasticsearch, proxy, docker

I want to test ELK.
It works fine
BUt when I want to do a

```
docker-compose up
```

behind a proxy

```
docker-compose up --no-recreate 
Building kibana
Step 1 : FROM kibana:latest
 ---> 544887fbfa30
Step 2 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y netcat
 ---> Running in 794342b9d807
```

It failed

```
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Is' OK with

```
docker build  --build-arg  http_proxy=http://proxy:3128  --build-arg https_proxy=http://proxy:3128 kibana
```

But when I redo a  docker-compose up, il tries to re-build, and failed to pass through proxy

Any help ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You will need [docker-compose 1.6.0-rc1](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases) in order to pass the proxy to your build through docker-compose.
See [commit 47e53b4](https://github.com/docker/compose/commit/47e53b49c2e02d268a637f810138bbcdd61bc28b) from [PR 2653](https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/2653) for [issue 2163](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2163).

> Move all build related configuration into a `build:` section in the service.
> Example:

```
web:
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile.name
    args:
       key: value
```

As [mkjeldsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/482758/mkjeldsen) points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34990458/docker-compose-build-and-http-proxy/34992794?noredirect=1#comment109306837_34992794)

> If `key` should assume the value of an environment variable of the **same name**, `value` can be omitted ([docker-compose ARGS](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#args)):
>
> Especially useful for `https_proxy`: if the `envvar` is unset or empty, the builder will not apply proxy, otherwise it will.

Comment: If `key` should assume the value of an environment variable of the same name, `value` can be omitted: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#args. Especially useful for `https_proxy`: if the envvar is unset or empty, the builder will not apply proxy, otherwise it will.

Comment: @mkjeldsen Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. What helped me was using the explicit version 2.2 and then build - args and - network as described in [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#network).

Answer (score 0):

VonC is right, it works for me by adding args section under the build lines in docker-compose file:

original:

```
  ssh:
      build: ssh/.
      container_name: ssh
    ports:
      - "3000:22"
    networks:
      vault_net:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.238.20
```

Modified:

```
  ssh:
    build:
      context: "ssh/."
      args:
        HTTP_PROXY: http://X.X.X.X:XXXX
        HTTPS_PROXY: http://X.X.X.X:XXXX
        NO_PROXY: .domain.ltd,127.0.0.1
    container_name: ssh
    ports:
      - "3000:22"
    networks:
      vault_net:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.238.20
```

Note that I have to add quotes for context since it needs to be formatted as string.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

did you try it on clean machine?

```
docker-machine stop default
docker-machine create -d virtualbox test
docker-machine start test
eval $(docker-machine env test)
docker-compose up
```